# Send input to a Python script which is already running

Tags: python, matlab

I am working on a tool developed in MATLAB, and I would like to be able to send input periodically to a Python script which is already running. To keep it simple, the Python script looks like this:

```
while(True):
    com = input('Command: ')
    print('Received:', str(com))
    # do something here
```

What I would like to achieve:

1. Open the above Python script which is waiting for input
2. Send a string as input, from another program (directly from my MATLAB, or by using an intermediate: another Python script, batch file maybe)
3. Repeat step 2 several times, without closing the original Python script

I am not interested in using command line arguments, since the script shall be kept running. I am also familiar with Python subprocess communication via PIPE, but that is not suitable for my purpose.

Is there any way I could implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: Python 3.x? There are some ways, just to name two [asyncio](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) or threading. But you have to get used to them and i think it is also possible with (named) pipes, where you already have experience. Why ist it not suitable?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 3.7.
I thought of using an intermediate script which gets a string as command line argument(from MATLAB), and somehow send it to the main script.
But in that case, the 2 processes are totally independent from eachother, and I cannot establish a communication using the subprocess library(since there is no parent-child, or any kind of relationship between them).

Comment: You can use socketing, see [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/50079-python-and-matlab-in-the-socket) thread on the Matlab forum. That way you can send any text to Python and act upon it.

Answer (score 0):

The socket approach from @rinkert s comment seems nice. If that isn't working for you and "named pipes" are suitable, in contrast to any pipes, this might help:

in Python:

```
import win32pipe, win32file, pywintypes

PIPENAME = r'\\.\pipe\testpipe'

print('receiver')
pipe = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(PIPENAME,
                                     win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                                     win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
                                     1,  # nMaxInstances
                                     65536,  # nOutBufferSize
                                     65536,  # nInBufferSize
                                     0, # 50ms timeout (the default)
                                     None) # securityAttributes
win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe)
keep_pipe = 1
try: # until KeyboardInterrupt
    while keep_pipe: #until you send 'quit'
        try:
            msg = win32file.ReadFile(pipe, 65536) #msg[0]:code [1]:message as bytes
            if str(msg[1]) == "b'quit\\r\\n'":
                print('quitting by message')
                win32pipe.DisconnectNamedPipe(pipe)
                win32file.CloseHandle(pipe)
                keep_pipe = 0
            else:
                print('Received:', msg[1].decode('utf-8'))
        except pywintypes.error as e:
            if e.winerror == 109: #no process on other side OR Pipe closed
                win32pipe.DisconnectNamedPipe(pipe)
                print("Reconnecting pipe")
                win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe)
            else:
                print(e)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('quitting by KeyboardInterrupt')
```

in Matlab:

```
NET.addAssembly('System.Core'); %# might be superfluous
pipeStream = System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe", System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection.Out);
sw = System.IO.StreamWriter(pipeStream);
sw.BaseStream.Connect(5)

for i=1:3 %you can use it for multiple messages
    sw.WriteLine('hello world')
    sw.Flush();
end

sw.WriteLine('quit')
sw.Flush();

sw.BaseStream.Dispose() %after the pipe is closed by this it has to be reopened
```

The Python part may have things you don't need (like the disconnectiong on 'quit'), but I had it lying around like this and some of those things might come in handy.

The Matlab part I just got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12657736/5124383) question and filled it up with some .NET. I assume there is a better way, but it does the trick.